# Jest + Babel in VS Code debugger causes breakpoints to move

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I am trying to debug a simple project using babel, jest, and vs code. When I set a breakpoint and then start debugging, my breakpoints jump around and are no longer where they were when I started. A sample repo can be seen here - https://github.com/RyanHirsch/starter-node

I've updated my `launch.json` to contain

```
{
  "name": "Jest",
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
  "stopOnEntry": false,
  "args": ["-i", "${file}"],
  "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "runtimeExecutable": null,
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "protocol": "inspector"
}
```

And my `.babelrc` looks like:

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"],
  "sourceMaps": "inline",
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "6.10"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I thought that the source map options were enough to get this to work but I was wrong. What needs to change in order to keep my breakpoints in their original locations? Specifically when trying to debug my tests.

==== Edit ====

Before my breakpoints are on test line 10 and implementation line 4:

[image: Before Debugging]

When I start debugging by selection my test file and then run Jest in the VS Code debug pane, my breakpoints jump to test line 9 and implementation line 6:
[image: During Debugging]

Running on Node 9.6.1 with the following extensions:

```
DavidAnson.vscode-markdownlint
EditorConfig.EditorConfig
Orta.vscode-jest
PKief.material-icon-theme
PeterJausovec.vscode-docker
Shan.code-settings-sync
bungcip.better-toml
dbaeumer.vscode-eslint
dracula-theme.theme-dracula
dzannotti.vscode-babel-coloring
eamodio.gitlens
esbenp.prettier-vscode
gerane.Theme-FlatlandMonokai
humao.rest-client
mauve.terraform
mikestead.dotenv
mjmcloug.vscode-elixir
mohsen1.prettify-json
ms-vscode.Theme-MaterialKit
ms-vscode.azure-account
ms-vscode.cpptools
ritwickdey.LiveServer
sbrink.elm
shanoor.vscode-nginx
vscodevim.vim
```

Comment: Can you show some screenshots of before run and after run? Where are you putting the breakpoints how you running it? Because the project breakpoints run great for me. Also mention the node and NPM version you use

Comment: Although this doesn't explain why this is happening for you, but you can always try adding `retainLines: true` to your `.babelrc` so that it doesn't confuse which line the breakpoint should be on.

Comment: Adding `retainlines` will break any column breakpoints and according to the docs produces "wacky code". It seems like the source maps should work :(

Comment: well, not that it helps a whole lot, but you're not alone https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/6008

Answer (score 8):

@RyanHirsch ; just use `retainLines": true` alongside `sourceMap: "inline"` in your babelrc and It will work.

Answer (score 6):

Got this issue (using jest 23.6.0), checked that this was a known issue on create react app, resolved on this pull request:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/3605/files

Applied the following config to my *launch.json*

`{
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Jest All",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest",
      "args": [
        "test",
        "--runInBand",
        "--no-cache"

      ],
      "sourceMaps": false,
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    },`

Managed to get it breaking on the right breakpoints.

Comment: Update, this worked a while but still failing, just rolled back to Jest 22, current configuration I'm using: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52454412/visual-studio-code-debugging-jest-breakpoints-not-working-as-expected

Comment: Update, both Jest and VS Code have enhanced it's integration,now is possible to easily integrate them on both create-react-app based applications and apps created from scratch, I have created a post to cover this topics: https://www.basefactor.com/using-visual-studio-code-to-debug-jest-based-unit-tests

Answer (score 2):

After much struggling, here's how I got Jest with Babel debugging to **consistently work and break on the correct lines.**

Mainly, I used the excellent [**Jest plugin for VSCode**](https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest) by developer '[Orta](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/publishers/Orta)', and via searching 'Jest' in the extensions pane of VSCode:

[image: How to find and install the extension via VSCode]

From there I just hit the `Debug` link that appears in my test, which allows me to correctly hit breakpoints in both my tests and application code.

#### Breakpoint successfully hit in the test file:

[image: Successful Jest test debugging via Orta's Jest VSCode plugin]

#### Breakpoint successfully hit in the source code file:

[image: Breakpoint successfully hit in the source code file]

Comment: I tried this, but it did nothing other than create random breakpoints in different files!

Answer (score 0):

The correct config which works for **babel-jest 25.0.0** & 
**jest 25.0.0** is the following:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug Jest Tests",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--inspect-brk",
                "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
                "--runInBand"
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
            "port": 9229
        }
    ]
}
```

For more information I took my config from the following [repository](https://github.com/hamzahamidi/jest-starter)

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me is the turning off sourcemap by adding `"sourceMaps": false` to the launch config. I don't fully understand why it works though.

Example:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Jest Current File",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
  "args": [
    "${relativeFile}",
    "--config",
    "jest.config.js",
    "--no-cache"
  ],
  "console": "integratedTerminal",
  "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
  "disableOptimisticBPs": true,
  "sourceMaps": false,
  "windows": {
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest",
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**Install node:**

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

**Install Chrome Plugin:**

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nodejs-v8-inspector-manag/gnhhdgbaldcilmgcpfddgdbkhjohddkj?hl=en

**In your terminal run the following script**

```
node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --runInBand
```

More reference for troubleshooting in vs code follow instruction in

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting

```
 {
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug Jest Tests",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--inspect-brk",
        "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
        "--runInBand"
      ],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    }
  ]
}
```

Babel will be converting es6 to es5, so its not dependent for inspecting.
For inspecting you need node and node chrome extension.

> Enjoy Coding

Comment: Seems that 'moving breakpoint' issue is happening again on jest 23.6.0, once it hits the first breakpoint, you can setup a breakpoint and it will stop