# Visual Studio Code debugging - Jest breakpoints not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, debugging, visual-studio-code, jestjs, breakpoints

Recently I have upgraded to Jest 23.x.x, using the same VSCode debugging configuration as in Jest 22.x.x, I get weird behaviors: breakpoints are moved, and you cannot really debug (not hitting the real line of code). If I downgrade to 22 everything works as expected.

Is there any breaking change or update from 22 to 23 to be aware of for this case?

My vscode debug launch configuration

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [    
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Jest All",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest",
      "args": [        
        "--runInBand",
        "--no-cache"        
      ],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    },
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Jest Current File",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest",
      "args": [
        "${relativeFile}",
        "--runInBand",
        "--no-cache"        
      ],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can open an issue in github.com/microsoft/vscode

Comment: Not sure if it could be a VSCode or Jest issue, and on the other hand, I'm thinking that I'm doing something wrong, because it looks like a too obvious error not to be detected